# functions /bin/false in shell script makes negative effect

Tags: function, shell

I was confused:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -f /etc/init.d/functions ] && . /etc/init.d/functions

[ 0 -eq 0 ] && action "Test" /bin/false || action "Test" /bin/true

echo "###############"

[ 0 -eq 0 ] && action "Test" /bin/true || action "Test" /bin/false
```

the result is:

```
Test                                                       [FAILED]
Test                                                       [  OK  ]
###############
Test                                                       [  OK  ]
```

does the action /bin/false function return false value that makes the statement behind || to be executed?
if I have to put /bin/false in "&&" block, what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that:

```
action "Test" /bin/false
```

returns `1` that causes command after `||` to execute as the failure action. **Effectively** this behaves like this:

```
[ 0 -eq 0 ] && { action "Test" /bin/false || action "Test" /bin/true; }
```

This is more of a reason to use `if/else/fi` and get the right behavior:

```
echo "###############"
if [ 0 -eq 0 ]; then
   action "Test" /bin/false
else
   action "Test" /bin/true
fi
```

This will output:

```
Test                                                       [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since /bin/false return false, it pass the || and return /bin/true

See it like this:

```
true && false || true -> true
true && true || false -> true
```

If you use

```
[ 0 -eq 0 ] && action "Test" /bin/false && action "Test" /bin/true
```

if will return false, as you expected?

See this

```
#!/bin/bash
[ 1 = 1 ] && echo "displayed because previous statement is true"

[ 1 = 0 ] && echo "not shown because previous statement is false"

[ 1 = 1 ] || echo "not shown because previous statement is true"

[ 1 = 0 ] || echo "displayed because previous statement is false"
```